# Can't get banner image to display using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When running my Rails (Blog) app, I can't get my banner image to display.
My files are as follows (the page show without error just no image):

application.js

```
//* require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.scss

```
 @import "bootstrap";
 @import "navbar";
```

_post.html.erb

```
<div class='col-sm-6 col-lg-4'>
   <div class="card">
      <div class="card-topper" style='background-image: 
         url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/113762/pexels-photo-113762-
         large.jpeg);'>
      </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h4>
          <p class="published-date">published Jan 14, 2016</p>
          <p class="card-text"><%= truncate(post.description, lenght: 130) 
          %></p>
          <%= link_to 'Read', post, class: 'btn btn-read' %>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From what I can see your div with the `card-topper` class has no content, if it has no height defined elsewhere, that might be the reason.

Comment: Here's the code: .posts.index {
    .card {
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0;
      height: 400px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      .card-topper {
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to rails. The image background will appear once you have **content** in your **DIV**. if you don't have content inside the **DIV**, better use `<img />` tag.

**Reference:**
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size

Image tag:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp